# Java: Search file for string in array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm making a user system in Java using text files and i'm trying to make it so that the same username can't register twice. It completely ignores it and allows for the creation anyway.

The code I have below is:

```
static boolean checkUsername(String u) { //Check the username and password
        boolean userFound = false;
         try { //Try and read our user file
             Scanner loginRead = new Scanner(loginFile); //Load the file into the scanner

             loginRead.useDelimiter("|"); //Split each set of user data into an array with |
             try {
                 if(loginRead.nextLine() ==null) {
                     return false;
                 } else {
                     while(loginRead.nextLine() !=null){ //Run line by line until we find this MF
                         String user_r = loginRead.next(); //loginRead[0] = Username
                         loginRead.next(); //Read the line

                         if(u.equals(user_r)){ //If we have a match
                              userFound=true;
                              break;   //Break the login script because we've struck gold
                         }
                     }
                 }
             } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
                 return false;
             }


         } catch (FileNotFoundException exceptionText) { //We couldn't find the user file.
             System.out.println("User file error");

         }

         return ((userFound==true) ? true : false); //Short hand if statement
         //to tell us if we found that user

    }
```

User file:

```
username|pwhash|fname|lname
username|pwhash|fname|lname
username|pwhash|fname|lname
username|pwhash|fname|lname
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: why do you do 2  loginRead.next(); in a row?

Comment: Can you also share your `loginFile` as well?

Comment: you need to return true when duplicate user found.

Comment: @Omore, sorry I missed the bottom out which does exactly that. mohit that has been added. 7663233 Good question, i'll change that.

Comment: Thanks it's my first comment as I just receive comments badge.

Comment: You can write `return ((userFound==true) ? true : false);` like `return userFound;`

Comment: Thanks @Jérôme, done that. I've just changed the delimiter variable to the following as I think that may have been contributing... But it hasn't fixed it. `Scanner userData = loginRead.useDelimiter("|");`

Comment: you do several nextLine before evaluating if the User is contained there you need to evaluate every single nextLine if the user can be found there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very, very late. But I re-did the code and here is what I went with, for anyone else wondering:

```
static boolean checkUsername(String u) throws IOException { //We use this function when registering a user, to make sure they don't already exist
        boolean userFound = false; //Our boolean for if the user exists
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("./loginData.dat")); //Load our loginData.dat file into the buffer
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) { //Read the file line by line
            String[] userDataNew=line.toString().split("\\|"); //Split our line up into an array using |

            if(userDataNew[0].equals(u)) { //We've found their username already
                userFound = true; //Set our user found bool to true
                break; //Break out of the foor loop
            }
        }
        return userFound; //Return true/false 
}
```